# Find Cube's Last Processing Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Where can I find when was the last time my cube was processed?

Are there any history records?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Data Tools.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, open up a new MDX Query tab, connect to your cube, and run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
```

The LAST_DATA_UPDATE column should give you what you are looking for.

I would suggest reading up on the SSAS DMVs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx#bkmk_ex).  They are very handy!